# SharePoint Online - Communication site - Hide page columns on small devices

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site, responsive

We are using a communication site on our SharePoint online pages.
Actually we are considering, if it is possible to specify in the standard page editing mode that columns should be hidden in small resolutions (responsive design).

[image]

We are trying to hide the images on the left and right side, if the screen is smaller.
In the options we only get how many columns and which color should be used:

[image]

Is there any chance to do this without programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Sharepoint has its own grid and responsive design.It will adjust based on the screen sizes.
You could refer to this article for more:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/design/grid-and-responsive-design

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The website on the link, I already visited...